# If all 3 cells equal "X", it changes colour of another cell

Tags: excel

I have been using Conditional Formatting > New rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format. I then set the fill colour and add the rule - =IF(AF9="X",AG9="X",AH9="X").

This seems to turn the cell green when 2 of the 3 cells have "X" entered but I need it to only turn green when all 3 have an "X".

Thanks

Comment: =IF(AND(AF9="X",AG9="X",AH9="X")) - I think...

Comment: Hmm... still not working!

Comment: you don't need the IF - simply `AND(AF9="X",AG9="X",AH9="X")` - this will return true or false - if true the condition is met and the cell turns green.